# Need to show HTML page (with CSS) as a book with page flipping

Tags: android, android-webview, android-gallery

So I have a local HTML file with CSS and I need to display this file in the form of a book (scroll left/right to view previous/next content, not up and down). I've thought of a really complicated ways to achieve this:

- A `Gallery` of `WebView`s
- Disable scrolling in the `WebView`
- On swipe, scroll the `WebView` down the height of the `WebView`

There's a couple of problems with this approach:

- I'd have to have the HTML content loaded for each `WebView` (extremely inefficient)
- There exists the possibility that at the bottom of the page, there would be some content partially hidden

I'm looking for some suggestions on how to approach this problem, as the only thing I've came up with sounds dreadful. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to find the answer for this question? If yes, please share the sample code.

Comment: I ended up using a single `WebView` and decided to use Javascript to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks.. Can you please describe the procedure and some code will will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two frames or iframes side by side and load odd page numbers in the left frame and even page numbers in the right frame.  Put some fancy control buttons on each page, or a javascript scrollbar under the frames, and a div with a page-flipping animation that you can turn on or off when pages are loaded into the frames.  I think it's totally doable, and could actually be pretty slick.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you totally, but here is a good example for page curl animation with custom view.

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/tree/master/src/fi