# Need to render HTML file as a book and retain CSS formatting on Android

Tags: html, css, android-webview

I apologize in adavance as a similiar question already exists here:
[Need to show HTML page (with CSS) as a book with page flipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303144/need-to-show-html-page-with-css-as-a-book-with-page-flipping)

Unfortunately it seems that the poster solved his own problem without revealing the details of the solution.

As I do not have the required reputation to comment on the original post, and also lack the ability to ask the poster directly, I am forced to simply ask the community for help.

I need exactly what is described in the previous post. I am currently able to display the entire html file but would like to display it as a book with the ability to swipe from page to page.

The only solution that I know how to perform currently is manually splitting the file into dozens of seperate .html files and switching between them as the user flips pages.

I realize that this is a terrible way to implement this and am looking for a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to find a solution after some research. The technique is to wrap each section  in div tags with the css attribute style="display:none" which will hide the section. You then inject Javascript into the application to change the appropriate page to style="display:block" which will display the associated section

```
<div id="page1" style="display:none">
Some Text Here
</div>
```